# How to address variables with paste0?

Tags: r, variables, paste

Let's say I have vectors x_1, x_2, x_3 and a vector with their names:

```
 x_1<-1:3
 x_2<-3:5
 x_3<-7:9
 names<-c("x_1", "x_2", "x_3")
```

Is it possible to address those vectors using another vector with their names ? For example:

```
 for (i in 1:length(names)) {
 print(paste0("x_",i)/2)
}
```

The example doesn't work, but that's what I'd like to do. Is there any function like "as.name" or whatever that converts paste0 output into a variable name ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may get the values of all the objects in `names` (it is better to use a different name as `names` is a `base R` function name) in a `list` with `mget`, divide by 2 and assign (`%=%` back to the `names`)

```
library(collapse)
names %=%  lapply(mget(names), `/`, 2)
```

-output

```
> x_1
[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5
> x_2
[1] 1.5 2.0 2.5
> x_3
[1] 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

---

In the `base R` `for` loop, we can use `assign`

```
for (i in seq_along(names)) {
 assign(paste0("x_",i), get(paste0("x_", i))/2)
}
```

-checking

```
> x_1
[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5
> x_2
[1] 1.5 2.0 2.5
> x_3
[1] 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a named list?

```
tibble::lst(x_1, x_2, x_3)[[names[1]]]
```

Then you can loop

```
for(i in names){
  print(tibble::lst(x_1, x_2, x_3)[[i]])
}
```

Comment: That works, I was just looking for a way to retrieve a variable name from a string. I've got it from the answers below. Thank you very much as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `eval(parse(text=...))` combination:

```
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  print(eval(parse(text=paste0("x_", i)))/2)
}
```

gives

```
[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5
[1] 1.5 2.0 2.5
[1] 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

Comment: Great, yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!